# How to add products from front-end side in Expresso Store?

Tags: expresso-store, product

I want to add products from front-end side with single product or package of product in Expresso Store ?

It is possible to do this in Expresso Store?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the [Channel Form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html) tags?

Comment: Since Expresso store product are just channel entries, I suppose indeed you can use the channel form. However you can add a expresso store input to and channel, I'm not sure if you can also add these modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Store supports [Channel Form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html) (previously called SafeCracker).

You can display the Store product details field in the Channel Form field the same way you do other custom fields, and your users will be able to create products on the front end.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the same exact thing you see in the control panel is available within a channel entries form or loop.

{exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}